# C Programming: Shared Memory Signal Hangs

Tags: c, signals, shared-memory

I have two programs one writes data to shared memory and the other reads from it. Writer is suppose to write data 0-9 in shared memory and then wait unit reader reads this data and display it on the screen and signals the writer process, then writer writes data 10-19 to shared memory and then wait until reader reads and display data to screen and signal writer to end process.

Writer code:

```
#define SHMKEY 75
int shmid;

void cleanup(int);

int main (void) {

    int *pint, *ppint, i;

    for (i=0;i<20;i++)  signal(i,cleanup); 

    shmid=shmget(SHMKEY, 128,0666|IPC_CREAT);
    pint=(int *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
    ppint=pint;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {  *ppint++ = i }; 
    *pint=-1;  
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);

    for(i=10;i<20;i++) {  *ppint++ = i }; 
    *pint=-1;  
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);

    return 0;
}

void cleanup(int x) { 
    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0);  
    exit(0);
}
```

Reader Code:

```
#define SHMKEY 75

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  //expects pid of writer as clarg
{
    int i, *pint, *pint1, shmid;
    int pid= atoi(argv[1]);

    shmid=shmget(SHMKEY, 128,0666);
    pint=(int *)shmat(shmid,0,0);


    while(*pint != -1); 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)  printf("%d\n",*pint++); 
    // Reset busy wait flag so it continues to wait
    *pint=0;  
    kill(pid, SIGCONT);
    printf("Signal 1\n");


    while(*pint != -1); 
    for(i=10;i<19;i++)  printf("%d\n",*pint++);
    kill(pid, SIGCONT);
    printf("Signal 2\n");
}
```

Outputs running two terminal windows:

```
$./writer &
[1] 9350

$ ./reader 9350
-1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Signal 1
(hangs)
```

I seems to be hanging after the second busy wait loop in the reader, but I don't understand why? since I send a signal before the busy wait to the writer to unset the flag *pint = -1.